# Which scriptures describe Dadhichi hiding Kshatriya children from Parashurama?

Tags: devi, parashurama

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadhichi) on Dadhichi says that he saved some Kshatriya children from Parashurama's wrath by hiding them in the Hinglaj Devi Temple.

[This site](http://brahmkshatriya.in/origin.htm#shelter) and [this wiki page on Hinglaj Mata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinglaj_Mata) gives an account of how a King known as Ratnasena of Sindh took shelter at Dadhichi's ashram as Parashurama wreaked havoc and his 5 queens gave birth to 5 sons in the ashram.

Ratnasena was killed by Parshurama when he ventured outside the ashram and Dadhichi disguised Ratnasena's children as brahmins to hide them.

One of the children named Jayasena returned to Sindh under a protection mantra of Hinglaj Devi given to him by Dadhichi. It is said Hinglaj Devi also asked Parashurama to stop his massacre.

Does this story have any scriptural basis or is it just a folktale?

Comment: Here this verse mention Some women hiding Kshatriya child "Mulaka" when parashurama was killing Kshatriyas , he was later called Nari-Kavacha ,and was
became the progenitor of Kshatriyas. But here no mentioning of Dadhichi only single verse and no other details. - https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/9/40

Comment: Note - There is much difference here  in this and Gita press version translation.In  Gita press translation the meaning is more clear.